# VNC connection to headless Ubuntu workstation - black screen after login

Tags: vnc, headless

I managed to be able to get to the logon screen of Ubuntu 16.04LTS via VNC/ssh following several nice guides on these websites:

http://machine-cycle.blogspot.com/2012/04/remote-gdm3-login-with-vnc.html
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11231
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

However, once I logged on all I see is a black screen and a cursor. With a display attached on the remote machine, the logon worked there, but is not shared via vnc. Without any monitor attached, I get back to the login screen immediately after successful login. The only configuration that somewhat worked was using the XFCE4 window manager, but that causes a number of applications to crash (RStudio). Therefore, I'd rather have it up and running with XUbuntu or Gnome.

Btw, VNC is no problem using the Remote Sharing AFTER login. But I really want a headless system (or with attached diplayport dongle emulating a display).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Geo

Comment: Did you happen to fix this problem?